# How to debug angular 2 app from VS2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.6

How can I configure a simple Angular 2.0 / TypeScript 1.6 project so I can run and **debug** the app from within Visual Studio 2015.

I have the simple 'getting started' project from angular.io.
The problem is that since app.js is loaded dynamically I cannot set breakpoints or debug the file from VS debugger.

I tried to load the file using plain script tag before the import, but the I get a 'required undefined' error on load.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 App01</title>
    <script src="../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!--<script src="../src/app/app.js"></script>-->

    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' } }
        });
        System.import('app/app');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

And app.ts

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
        <h2>xx-{{txt}}-yy</h2>
    `
})
class AppComponent {
    txt: string;
    constructor() {
        this.txt = "hello from AppComponent - hmmm, cannot debug this from vs";
    }
}
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: I can't figure this out either. I'm stuck in the very same place as you. I've verified that my sourcemaps are correct because I can Start Without Debugging into IE and it correctly loads my .ts file and allow me to step through it; but that's through the IE debugger. I don't understand why VS isn't loading the sourcemap when IE is able to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to debug the sourcemaps from chrome.  There is an option to enable source maps within chrome.  As for why its not working in IE, I am unsure.

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/05/27/TypeScript-debugging-in-Visual-Studio-with-IE-Chrome-and-Firefox-using-Source-Maps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how systemjs does the lazy-loading. Somebody told me, it should be possible to change that by editing the systemsjs-config. But i could not get this to work.

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this working. Instead I have switched to WebStorm when playing with Angular 2, there was no problem getting it working there.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted two working samples to Github:
[angular2-systemjs-dotnet-core](https://github.com/luiscantero/angular2-systemjs-dotnet-core) and 
[angular2-webpack-dotnet-core](https://github.com/luiscantero/angular2-webpack-dotnet-core).